# Update each row with a new entity

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, bulkupdate

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE public.test2
(
    id integer,
    test_id integer
)
```

Table `test2` has two rows (1, null) and (2, null). Table `test` has nothing. Now I want to fill test_id by creating new rows in `test`. I nead a new entity each time so that I will have (1, 1), (2, 2), etc. I try to prepare `update` query with an `insert` statement but I don't understand how to do it. This is what I try:

```
update t2 set t2.test_id = t.id
from test2 t2 full join (INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (default) RETURNING id) t on t2.test_id = t.id
```

but I get the following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 2: from test2 t2 full join (INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (defaul...
                                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 65
```

Can I create the query I want somehow?

Comment: Do you really have just one column in `test`, or there are others?

Comment: This is just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just one column in the target table makes things a little tricky. It might be simpler to generate and assign the new ids first, using `next_val`, and then `insert` the values in `test` (we need option `overriding system value` to insert into a `generated always` colum,)

```
with t2 as (
    update test2
    set test_id = nextval('test_id_seq')
    where test_id is null
    returning test_id
) 
insert into test(id) overriding system value 
select test_id from t2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c75401c13d57463f5d1c5152366c6ae)**